# Synonyms of Veteran and Rookie in terms of research methodology

Tags: synonyms

I am comparing two research methods. They both do the same thing. However, one method performs far better than other primarily because it has evolved over years and is therefore more seasoned:

1) Researchers have worked on the first method for almost 10 years. Therefore its results are very robust and performance very good.

2) Second method is relatively new. Although it does the same thing as the first method, its performance is very poor, primarily because Researchers have started working on it only recently.

Basically, the first method is a veteran and the second is a Rookie. I was wondering, what can be some good synonyms words for saying the same thing for research methods?

Comment: ***Established***, ***expert*** (there’s also the specific term for computer systems experts in a given field have spent time teaching about that field: *expert systems*; there’s an article on Wikipedia).

Comment: Established research or expert research doesn't sound right. They sound good when referring to a person, but when referring to a research not so much.

Comment: I was thinking more about software and systems, not research. For systems, you can even say things like *seasoned on*. For research, you need something like *heavily relied upon in later literature*, but off the top of my head, I can’t think of a word to capture that sentiment.

Comment: I also thought you were referring to systems and software and then I realized my question wordings were a little vague. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

The first system could be referred to as being "mature" or "well-tested" while the second may be "evolving", "in beta testing", or "fledgling".